# DLL not found in redistributable (biddll.dll)

Tags: c++, dll, dllimport, ntdll

I’m having difficulty getting the sample code for tws api running. I’ve successfully run it on a borrowed laptop but the same version fails on my own windows 10 laptop. When running on Release mode in Win32, I get the popups
`The code execution cannot proceed because biddll.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.` and `The procedure entry point ?cancelOrder@EClient@@QAEXJ@Z could not be located in the >dynamic link library C:\Eclipse-workspace\TWS >API\samples\Cpp\TestCppClient\ReleaseTestCppClient.exe.`

I’ve read through several questions similar to this. I’ve tried installing the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2022 for both x86 and x64 from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170. I’ve tried loading biddll.dll from another folder but it gives the message “Module was built without symbols.”. I’ve run “sfc /scannow” for broken files. The issue persists. biddll.dll still seems to not be anywhere in the system files or the API files. The only version is the one I copied from another version of the project.

Comment: Is it supposed to be `bi.dll` and the debug version `bid.dll`?  If it's the latter, debug system dlls are typically not redistributable, but must be downloaded as part of development.

Comment: @franji1 Ok, so it wouldn't be part of the redistributable. Do you think that would be fixed by redownloading the TWS API or would that be something from Visual Studio? It was named biddll.dll which I thought was strange to have as the naming convention.

Comment: ***Do you think that would be fixed by redownloading the TWS API or would that be something from Visual Studio*** I would say very unlikely. If this is a Debug dll in a release application the problem is an improperly configured project dependencies.

Comment: @drescherjm Is there something else that would likely solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions. I uninstalled TWS API and reinstalled it. I made sure to build for Release. It sounds like there was a mismatch between some debug libraries and it started pulling them instead. There may have been some unexpected behavior from installing several versions while troubleshooting as well.